# Flutter device selection not showing up (target selector)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

in one of my Flutter project I cannot any longer see a target selector to select the device 
[image: picture with selector NOT showing up]
It is interesting because if I open another project the selector is there
[image: picture with selector showing up] 
so there must be an issue with my first project or a setting I need to adjust...

Any help? How can I have my device selector back???

Comment: May be you have not setup environment variable for android sdk

Comment: I had this issue when I installed Android Studio on another device and wanted to develop a flutter project further there. I had installed the flutter plugin to Android Studio but did not configure it. 

In Android Studio -> Tools -> Flutter I triggered a "flutter pub get" and the IDE brought me to the flutter plugin configuration where I had to manually specify the flutter SDK path. After that the build targets showed up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had one Flutter project that always opened without the "Flutter Device Selection" drop-down and the "Run 'main.dart'" menu item was always greyed out. Other projects worked fine. After following the steps below, the problematic project could build and run in the emulator properly.

- close the project in Android Studio
- rename or delete the `.idea` folder in the root of your project
- open the project again

Comment: Updated in realtime when I removed the .idea folder!

Lol at OP's accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

What solved it for me was just to check the "Enable Dart support for the project [project name]" checkmark, at
Android Studio > Preferences > languages & Frameworks > Dart,
originally got the solution from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3105)

Answer (score 7):

From **Preferences** > **Languages & Frameworks** > **Dart**, select **Enable Dart support for the project '<project name>'** if it is not enabled.

If it was enabled, disable it and apply changes. Then re-enable it and click **OK**. You should see the Flutter Device Selection now.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after the current upgrade in Giraffe,  All that was wrong was I had to redirect the flutter SDK.  Soon as I updated this it activated the selection box.

SDK path screen capture
[image: SDK path screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the issue for a few hours and it seems like it comes and goes. I think for anyone who is also seeing the issue where you only see the loading word, can see devices, but can't run your code. In the terminal type

```
flutter run -d emulator-5554
```

where `emulator-5554` is the name of the device you want to connect to.

Comment: `flutter run -d <device>` was what I was looking for! Thanks, loads! Here is an upvote

Answer (score 0):

I too facing the problem. Tried this one it worked for me:

- Right-click in this area, selecting any one option
- [image: Right-click in this area, selecting any one option]
- You will see " customize toolbar" options.
- After selecting, [image: Image 2 selecting options in]
- Click on the Plus icon and select add action.
  [image: Click on Add Action]
- Search for Flutter.DeviceSelector and apply and ok.

[image]

- If Flutter.DeviceSelector does not show up then try selecting the option
  Android.NavBar ToolBar and click on plus icon, add action and search for
  Flutter.DeviceSelector

[image]

**Then you are good to go**

Reference :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6270

Answer (score -4):

Today the selector is back.... what an illuminati mystery !