# In Android Studio, the "run" button is disabled / grayed-out, when cloning a flutter project from Git

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter, dart

I just started learning flutter, and I wanted to clone a flutter project from git. When ever I clone a project and open it in android studio, the "run" button is disabled. The "Flutter device selection" dropdown is also not visible.

This does not happen when I created a flutter project from scratch but only when I clone it I face these issues.

[image]

The above pic shows the issue. 
I have tried:
**1) restarting the editor, 2) file -> invalidate caches/ restart**, **3) file -> project structure -> modules and removed the existing "content root" and adding it again**. Nothing worked.

My **flutter doctor -v** shows the following:
[image]

This is how my editor looks when I create a flutter project from scratch:
[image]

I have tried finding answers online but nothing worked. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you done packages get to make sure yout have the packages from the pubspeck file? Also have you tried creating a new project and then copying the contents of this project that one?

Comment: I did do the "packages get" and "flutter pub get". I did not copy the contents to a new file, I want to fix this problem normally so that when I decide to clone a really huge project, copying each file will not be possible.

Comment: Can you run the project from the command line with "flutter run"?

Comment: Do any of these answers fix your issue: [Flutter device selection not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885451) ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix. Open a different project (I have only been testing on flutter projects so far), then **file -> open -> your project**, in the dialogue pop up which asks do you want to open in **this window** or **new window**, select **new window**.